# Random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ (probability to be again in the starting point after n steps)

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

> > Consider the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, where the probability of going one step to the right from any given state shall be $p\in (0,1)$. Starting in 0, what is the probability of returning to 0 in $n$ steps?

First of all, I denote this probability by $p_{00}^{(n)}$. Then if $n$ is odd, then the probability is 0, right?

Then I tried to do it for n=2 and n=4.

n=2:

$$
p_{00}^{(2)}=p_{01}^{(1)}(1-p)+p_{0-1}^{(1)}p=p_{01}(1-p)+p_{0-1}p=p(1-p)+(1-p)p=2(1-p)p
$$

n=4:
$$
p_{00}^{(4)}=p_{01}^{(3)}(1-p)+p_{0-1}^{(3)}p=...=6p^2(1-p)^2
$$

Is that right?

But how can I get the result for any even number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us take $n$ even.

You have to have as many left moves than right moves.

The probability of getting, for example, the first $n/2$ left then the next $n/2$ right is
$$
p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2}
$$

But there are other possibilities: there are $n$ moves, $n/2$ of which must be left.
Hence you must multiply the base probability by
$
\binom n{n/2}
$.

The probability is eventually
$$\binom n{n/2}p^{n/2}(1-p)^{n/2}
$$

---

check: with $n=4$ we have $\binom n{n/2} = \frac{4\times 3}{2\times 1} = 6$ so it is coherent with your computation.

Comment: Is there a special Markov chain property that I have to use or this more combinatorical?

Comment: this is combinatorical at this point. But probability will come soon ;)

Comment: is the answer clear?

Comment: Do not see why the binomial coefficient.

Comment: take $n=4$. There are the following ways to be right: LLRR LRLR LRRL RLLR RLRL RRLL. The number of these is the number of ways to select, from the $n$ locations, the $n/2$ locations of the 'L' characters. There are $\binom n{n/2}$ of them (remember the definition of the binomial coefficient)

Comment: Now I do understand! Thank you